# Dummy Sampler under Runtime Controller duplicate requests

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a Simple Test Plan:

- Thread Group

  - Runtime Controller

    - Dummy Sampler

      - JSR223 Post Processor

Which works fine, **unless** I uncheck the `Simulate response time(sleep)` checkbox

Then It sends more than 300 request per seconds! (I see it using log in my post processor)

Without controller it works fine and also with different controller as `Simple Controller`

I didn't find in [Dummy Sampler documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) any indication of such behavior.

Should this checkbox never be uncheck under Runtime controller?

I'm not sure if it's a bug in JMeter or plugin or just wrong settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) runs samplers inside it until your reach the configured "Runtime" attribute value.

So if you uncheck in Dummy Sampler the "Simulate response time(sleep)", you'll end up having this sampler return nearly immediately and as a consequence execute much more in the configured time than if it's unchecked.

So I would say, configuration issue.

JMeter documentation has been improved following your question:

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?rev=1813452&view=rev

Comment: So instead of "how long its children are **allowed** to run" it mean how long its children **will** run? it behave as a loop with specific time it execute?

Comment: I updated answer and documentation has been clarified in JMeter